What is the explanation for and significance of the time-stopping ability in Megalopolis?
In Francis Ford Coppola's sci-fi film Megalopolis (2024), the protagonist, Cesar Catilina (played by Adam Driver), has the ability to stop time for everything else but himself, a power reminiscent of Za Warudo in JoJo's Bizarre Adventure.
Cesar’s overarching goal is to construct "Megalopolis," a utopian city made possible by a futuristic "miracle building material" called Megalon. Is his time-stopping ability connected to Megalon, or is it innate?
At one point in the film, Cesar loses his power while imprisoned. Later, with encouragement from Julia, he regains the ability and even uses it to stop time "for Julia," allowing both of them to move freely while the world remains frozen.
In the final scene, Cesar asks Julia to stop time. She does—revealing that she, too, has acquired this power—and time freezes for everyone and everything except their baby.
What is the explanation for and significance of the time-stopping ability in Megalopolis? Why is it limited to Cesar (and later extended to Julia and their baby)? Could this power be a metaphor for something deeper?

Most of the reviews I've read suggest that it's inexplicable or unexplained
